# Including JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I found online a jQuery sound plugin (no flash) which is part of script.aculo.us' sound.js (http://script.aculo.us), based on code by Jules Gravinese (http://www.webveteran.com/).

doesn't work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/sound.js"></script>
```

works:

```
<? include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/js/sound.js");?>
```

What should be changed, so my test.php works with the normal include method?
Why do this script only work with query/1.4.2/jquery.min.js and not with jquery/1.11.1/ or my jquery-2.1.0.min.js

test.php

```
<img src="/bilder/flaggen/englisch.png" onclick="$.sound.play('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=en&q=Test')" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">
```

sound.js

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   (function($) {

    $.sound = { 
    tracks: {},
    enabled: true,
    template: function(src) {
    return '<embed style="height:0" loop="false" src="' + src + '" autostart="true"    hidden="true"/>';
},
play: function(url, options){
    if (!this.enabled)
        return;
    var settings = $.extend({
        url: url,
        timeout: 2000
    }, options);

    if (settings.track) {
        if (this.tracks[settings.track]) {
            var current = this.tracks[settings.track];
            // TODO check when Stop is avaiable, certainly not on a jQuery object
            current.Stop && current.Stop();
            current.remove();  
        }
    }

    var element = $.browser.msie
        ? $('<bgsound/>').attr({
            src: settings.url,
            loop: 1,
            autostart: true
          })
        : $(this.template(settings.url));

    element.appendTo("body");

    if (settings.track) {
        this.tracks[settings.track] = element;
    }

    if(options){
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.remove();
        }, options.timeout)
    }

    return element;
}
};

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Your demo link please?

Comment: http://www.lern-online.net/test.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is already in a `.js` file, you don't need:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

at the beginning

and

`</script>`

at the end

Also, it doesn't work with the latest version of `JQuery` because of the updates in the latest versions. Alot of functions in the older versions have either been removed or renamed in the newer version.

Every script that uses jQuery is written and tested against a particular version of jQuery. Sometimes, it works with more than one version of jQuery and sometimes it only works with one particular version of jQuery.

It is the responsibility of the author of the script that uses jQuery to specify what versions of jQuery it is compatible with. It is the responsibility of the person using the script to know and understand what version of jQuery is required and to create the proper environment (with the right version of jQuery present) for the script to work properly.

A particular version of jQueryUI is compatible only with certain versions of core jQuery. Likewise, jQueryUI plug-ins are compatible only with certain versions of both jQueryUI and jQuery. You yourself must mix and match compatible versions of all of these.

Take a look at this for example:

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Also here is an overview of the newer JQuery 1.11 and 2.1.0

http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I when I delete the script-tags it shows the  whole js-code (with the editing of Luke also)

Comment: "Thanks for your Edit. Now it works perfectly. - Grischa" what is that about then?

Comment: I said the same thing though... Since the file is already in a .js file, you don't need:

<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: I'm sorry only on my test.php it shows the whole js-code from sound.php

Comment: Use the script tag in the html page... Don't use it on a .js file

Comment: Now I have also a question how to use the code for many tausend times in many files, so I want a shorter version, if it is possible, but I get here very fast many negative votes ;-(

Comment: put it in a .js file ;) and use the <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script> to embed it

Comment: yes yes, I understand it. I mean something else. See the code for this vocabulary table. I add the sound-icon with the js-task for the first eleven word-pairs, but I think their is a shorter version possible. I have many files like this in many languages ...http://www.lern-online.net/russisch/schreiben/vokabeln/arbeit/

Comment: Not the best person to provide you help on that... sorry... but one last thing I would say is that on your homepage you can remove the whole script... since it is the same as in the .js file so just embed the .js file and remove the whole script from the html page

Comment: I mean, remove the whole script even what is inside the style tag in the main page since you are already embedding the .js file

Comment: <img src="/bilder/symbole/play.png" onclick="$.sound.play('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&tl=de&q=der akademische Beruf')" style="cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;">  I don't understand what you mean,sorry

Comment: replace everything in your test.php with this http://pastie.org/pastes/9312632/text?key=2sxkqxpos99eebbeq3rxq

Comment: I had include it with php and with  <script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/sound.js"></script> forget to delete the php-include, but it is only a test file, so I search a better solution to use the $.sound.play('translate.google.com/translate... for many many words or expressions ;-(

Answer (score 0):

To make your first example work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/data/js/sound.js"></script>
```

remove the  tags from your .JS file.